# How do you get a composite USB Linux device with HID to wake up a suspended host?

Tags: c, kernel, embedded, embedded-linux, kernel-module

The embedded system that I'm working with runs the 3.18 Linux kernel and when connected to a PC acts as a composite USB device with HIDBP functionality (allows you to connect a keyboard and mouse to it). However, the problem I'm having is that a keyboard or mouse connected to it doesn't seem to wake up the host PC when it goes into full system suspend (a mouse connected directly to a PC can wake it up though). I'm just wondering, is this a linux kernel bug and if so how would one go about fixing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Your device must support DEVICE_REMOTE_WAKEUP, see USB specification. (and the appropriate USB driver on the host of course, but this should be the case for HID).  The HID Boot Protocol (HIDBP) provides more ore less a subset of the HID capabilities. Maybe remote wake up is not supported by HIDBP?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this feature has not been implemented for USB HID composite devices in the mainline kernel as of version 4.10.17